# Show the name of the parent function in the warning message

Tags: r, warnings

I have a helper function for displaying warnings:

```
mywarn <- function() {
  warning("I warn you")
}
```

If I call the function directly, I get the name of the function where the error occurred:

```
mywarn()
> Warning message:
  In mywarn() : I warn you
```

However I want to use the warning function from within several other functions:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  x <- x^2
  mywarn()
  x
}
```

But then it still shows the name of my warning function when warning is displayed:

```
myfun(10)
> Warning message:
  In mywarn() : I warn you
```

What is the best way to make the warning message display `myfun` instead of `mywarn` ?

Comment: I've edited my solution to something that seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you pointed out that other solutions to your question fail on cases like

```
sapply(10, myfun)
```

where they display something like

```
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : I warn you
```

I think this is nearly unavoidable without debug information.  In the `sapply()` call, `myfun` is an object; `sapply` doesn't care about its name.  So to put "myfun" into the message instead of the local variable in the `sapply` implementation, your `mywarn` would need to recognize that it was being called from `sapply`, and look further up the call stack to find the name of the function being called.  And there are lots of other functions besides `sapply` that it would have to handle, so this isn't a feasible approach.

If you happen to know that this is going to be a problem, you can work around it by making `myfun` do more work.  Instead of calling `mywarn` with simply the error message, it could pass its own name as part of the message.  This could be as simple as

```
mywarn("myfun")
```

or more elaborate like

```
mywarn(call = substitute(myfun(x),list(x = substitute(x))))
```

(where some of the ugliness could probably be moved into `mywarn`, but the presence of `myfun(x)` is essential).

You can do a lot more if you have enabled debug information in your source.  This is the default if you're using `source()`,
but it's optional for package source code.

For example, if you put the code below in a file named `test.R` and call `source("test.R")`, you'll get the output as shown:

```r
myfun <- function(x) {
  x <- x^2
  mywarn()
  x
}

mywarn <- function (msg = "I warn you", call = sys.call(sys.parent()))
{   
  calls <- sys.calls()
  for (i in rev(seq_along(calls))) {
    location <- getSrcref(calls[[i]])
    if (!is.null(location)) {
      call <- NULL
      filename <- getSrcFilename(location)
      linenum  <- getSrcLocation(location)
      functionname <- findLineNum(attr(location, "srcfile"), linenum)
      if (length(functionname) < 1) prefix <- "At "
      else prefix <- paste0("In ", functionname[[1]]$name, "() at ")
      msg <- sprintf("%s%s#%d: %s", prefix, basename(filename), linenum, msg)
    }
  }
  warning(simpleWarning(msg, call))
}

sapply(10, myfun)
```

```
Warning message:
At test.R#25: In myfun() at test.R#3: I warn you
```

which indicates that your source file line 25 called something that eventually got to `myfun()` in your source file line 3 and issued the warning.  You can make the prefix more or less informative according to your taste; I'd probably only include the closest location (`In myfun() at test.R#3:`) for example.

If you are working in a situation where the debug info isn't present, it will fall back to @KonradRudolph's solution.

Comment: The ugliness can be avoided by writing `mywarn(call("myfun", x))` ;-)

Comment: Incidentally, *`sapply`* could avoid this issue, but it would make its implementation substantially more complex. I actually half expected the `purrr::map*` functions to behave better, but they have the exact same behaviour. Improving this would be a good project.

Comment: Out of all the answers received this seems to be most on point so far. Thou I dislike passing function name manually, but probably that's unavoidable. And your second attempt is a bit too complex for my taste, but also on point. I will wait for a few days, maybe someone else will have some other ideas, if not - will be glad to accept this.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is by explicitly constructing a `warning` condition object with a suitable call object, and passing *that* to `warning`. This overrides the default logic which uses the calling function.

```
mywarn <- function (call = sys.call(sys.parent())) {
  warning(simpleWarning("I warn you", call))
}
```

```
myfun(10)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In myfun(10) : I warn you
> ```

Comment: Very nice to see so quick replies - so first - thanks! The problem with this approach seems to be that it breaks down with, for example, `sapply(10, myfun)`

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius That's a consequence of how `sapply` is implemented. Calling `warning` directly would have the same behaviour. This is a *general* feature of higher functions in R, and there is really no good way around this. However, that’s why my `mywarn` function has defined `call` as an *argument*, so the caller can customise it. If `myfun` knows that it will be invoked from `sapply`, it can provide its own `call`  object to `mywarn`, e.g. `mywarn(call("myfun", x))`.

Comment: Very good point that calling `warning()` directly gets into the same issue with `sapply`.  But it's hard for me to see what the issue is. In plain terms it sounds easy  to "always show the name of the direct parent that called me". Both with myfun -> mywarn and with sapply -> myfun -> mywarn the direct parent seems to be the same. Or do you think I am missing some hidden complexity here?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius What you are missing is that functions in R intrinsically don’t have names. They are just objects that live somewhere in memory. You can *bind* them to a name, but there is no 1-to-1 mapping. And when you pass a function to `sapply` it gets a different name (the name of the parameter: `FUN`). In particular, consider what you want to be printed if you use an anonymous function: `sapply(10, \(x) { mywarn(); x ^2 })`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Yeah this now seems obvious, within `sapply()` `myfun` gets a name of the argument `FUN`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```r
warnme <- function() {
  call <- deparse(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]])
  warnmessage <- sprintf("Warning in %s", call)
  warning(warnmessage, call. = FALSE)
}

f <- function(x) {
  warnme()
}

f(2)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the fast response. I've tried similar things on my own, and the problem here is that it seems to breakdown when called like that: `sapply(2, f)`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Still not 100% to the OP's requirements, but perhaps this can help. Show the warning for the function call triggering the warning and add a traceback to follow the functions downwards till the warning function is called.

```
mywarn <- function () {
  msg <- sys.calls()
  warning(
    sprintf("In %s : I warn you\n", gsub("[[:space:]]", "", msg[1][1], perl = TRUE)),
    "Traceback : \n", 
    sapply(msg[2:length(msg)], \(x) sprintf("\t%s\n", deparse(x)))
  , call. = F)
}

mywrap <- function(x) myfun(x); mywrap(2)

# Warning message:
#   In mywrap(2) : I warn you
# Traceback : 
#   myfun(x)
#   mywarn()
```

**original answer**

Not 100% perfect, but this is the closest I get to handle all 3 scenario's

```
mywarn <- function () {
  msg <- deparse(sys.calls()[[1]])[[1]]
  warning(sprintf("In %s : I warn you", msg), call. = FALSE)
}


myfun <- function(x) {
  x <- x^2
  mywarn()
  x
}

myfun(10)

# Warning message:
# In myfun(10) : I warn you 

sapply(10, myfun)

# Warning message:
# In sapply(10, myfun) : I warn you 

sapply(10, \(x) { mywarn(); x ^2 })

# Warning message:
# In sapply(10, function(x) { : I warn you
```

Comment: This solution will no longer show meaningful results when the `sapply` call itself is nested deeper inside another function rather than being called at the top level.

Comment: Hello, seems like a nice attempt, but, in addition to what @KonradRudolph said, will also fail with a simple wrapper: `mywrap <- function(x) myfun(x); mywrap(2)` - "warning messsage in mywrap(2)" ...

Comment: I agree it is not perfect, I updated my answer and still not perfect, but it shows the parent function triggering the warning with a traceback to "follow" the path towards the error function.